# random element from an array is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've done my shot as a beginner JS coder and reworked a quote generator app from an array on the click of a button. I managed to display next element each time I press the button. However, in the tutorial the elements were displayed at random, so I followed the instructions, but instead of a random quote I get "undefined". I'm stuck. It seems to me that I've done everything correctly but I might have slipped somewhere. Can anyone help me?

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let output = document.getElementById("output");
let quotes = [
  "The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we   fall. -Nelson Mandela",
  "The way to get started is to quit talking and begin doing. -Walt Disney",
  "Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's life. Don't be trapped by dogma – which is living with the results of other people's thinking. -Steve Jobs",
  "If life were predictable it would cease to be life, and be without flavor. -Eleanor Roosevelt",
  "If you look at what you have in life, you'll always have more. If you look at what you don't have in life, you'll never have enough. -Oprah Winfrey",
  "If you set your goals ridiculously high and it's a failure, you will fail above everyone else's success. -James Cameron",
  "Life is what happens when you're busy making other plans. -John Lennon",
];
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let randomQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.lenth)];
  output.innerHTML = randomQuote;
});
```

```html
<h1>Quote Generator</h1>
<div class="content">
  <button id="btn">Press for a new Quote!</button>
  <p id="output">Press the button to generate a quote.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo in `quotes.lenth`

Answer (score 2):

Your code perfect just `quotes.lenth` --> `quotes.length` :)

Comment: Vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo. There's an explicit reason there just for cases like this. Don't try and farm rep, especially when the exact same topic has been raised in a comment.

Comment: @j08691 I should have done as you said, sorry for that